# Adding an APP of type Wiki library VS adding new enterprise wiki subsite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, library, app

What are the differences between adding new Subsite of type "Publishing >> Enterprise Wiki" , and just adding a new Wiki Library App to any site ? and when to use each ?

Thanks

Comment: Well in the first case it creates a full sub web, in the other just a library on the existing web..

Comment: if we talk about the capabilities & the features these both offer . is there any thing i can do in an enterprise wiki sub site that is not available in a wiki library App or Vice versa?